Power Automate Approvals test widget no longer working
As of yesterday when i checked the Power Automate approvals test widget is no longer working. I haven't looked at the widget in a few weeks, so I am not sure exactly when it stopped working. The widget showed the current user's pending approvals in a card view, without the left menu bar, that is shown in the Power Automate web app. It was great for users to see their current approvals without them seeing the options to create Flows etc.
The url is :  https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/test/approvalcenterwidget/
The Microsoft site that references this widget is at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/embed-flow-dev
Does anyone know of an alternative or different url to this widget?
